# Heroku error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, heroku

I've been searching around on this one for a while and can't find anything that seems to be applicable in my situation. I've been staring at these logs and I can't see what the problem is. 
I am trying to deploy my nodejs and react app to heroku but getting error again and again.
I have done heroku logs and I am getting these logs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTqcv.png)

Comment: Could you give us more log lines? The few ones just before the state change should be much more helpful.

Comment: can we see your server.js or index.js entry point file?